# Laravel vue won't return meta tags

Tags: laravel, vuejs2, meta-tags

I provided meta in my `vue-router` but it doesn't return in my html

## Code

`router sample`

```
{
            path: '/',
            name: 'home',
            component: Home,
            meta: {
                title: 'Home Page - Welcome',
                metaTags: [
                  {
                    name: 'description',
                    content: 'The home page of our example app.'
                  },
                  {
                    property: 'og:description',
                    content: 'The home page of our example app.'
                  }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            path: '/login',
            name: 'login',
            component: Login,
            meta: { title: 'Login' }
        },
```

`beforeeach`

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
        if (localStorage.getItem('myApp.jwt') == null) {
            next({
                path: '/login',
                params: { nextUrl: to.fullPath }
            })
        } else {
            let user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myApp.user'))
            if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.is_admin)) {
                if (user.is_admin == 1) {
                    next()
                }
                else {
                    next({ name: 'userboard' })
                }
            }
            next()
        }
    } else {
        next()
    }
});
```

This is how my page head is look like:

[image: one]

and no sign of meta in browser as well:

[image: two]

## Questions

1. How to fix this issue?
2. How can I get title for dynamic pages like single post components?

..........

Answer (score 1):

You would need to add a way for the tags to be updated in the DOM as `vue-router` won't do this for you out-of-the-box.

You could try adding an after hook with something like:

```
router.afterEach((to, from) => {

    document.title = to.meta && to.meta.title ? to.meta.title : ''; // You can add a default here

    Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[data-vue-meta]')).map(el => el.parentNode.removeChild(el));

    if (to.meta && to.meta.metaTags) {
        to.meta.metaTags.map(tagDef => {
            let tag = document.createElement('meta');

            Object.keys(tagDef).forEach(key => tag.setAttribute(key, tagDef[key]));

            tag.setAttribute('data-vue-meta', '');

            return tag;
        }).forEach(tag => document.head.appendChild(tag));
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks, and for my second question? do you have any solution for it?

Comment: @mafortis set the `document.title` in the component. You could try adding a watcher for the `$route` or if you're using ajax to get the data for the component 
then set it in the `success`/`then` method.

Comment: I've just tried this but ddn't work,  `created() {
                document.title = this.$route.title;
                document.head.querySelector('meta[name=description]').content = 'New Description';
        },`

Comment: @mafortis Wouldn't it be `this.$route.meta.title`? What error are you getting?

Comment: return undefined.